# Process in not getting complete in IntelliJ

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I am facing an issue where IntelliJ is not completed Code run for of one my Selenium Script. I need to manually close Test Execution ever time.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/to/chromedriver");

    WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/crm/free-crm.html");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='namefield']")).sendKeys("Prabeen");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("Prabeen");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("Prabeen");


    //driver.close();
}
```

[image]

I always need to click on STOP RUN icon.

Can Someone suggest me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by _IntelliJ is not completed Code run_ Does it show test running process infinite ? Or just browser remain open after execution done ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Does the _namefield_, _email_ and _password_ field gets populated?

Comment: Yes, Everything worked fine but the Execution session is still active which Was not the case in Selenium 3 version. I am forced to add System.exit(0) to achieve this. @DebanjanB

Comment: @NarendraR Let me write complete step....    1. Write Selenium Script with Driver.quit or without This . 2. Run Script.  3. Browser will launch and steps will be formed. 4. execution session should get complete in eclipse or any IDE when scripts complete......... It is not happening in selenium 4 but working in selenium 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is one of the known issues in the selenium 4 upgrade. I have seen same issue raised on multiple platforms. Issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8159 is still open for the same.